# Cannot collect all nodes of Google search result with goquery: some nodes are missing

Tags: html, go, web-scraping, goquery

I am trying to collect results of a google search page in GoLang using the goquery library. In order to achieve this, I am collecting all nodes of a goquery selection with goquery. The problem is that the selection returned by Find("*") does not seem to contain all the nodes of the HTML document. Question: does the method collect ALL nodes with the whole tree structure or not ? If not, is there a method to collect them all ?

I tried using the goquery Find("*") method applied to the whole document selection. So nodes with certain attributes are not returned, although they are in the HTML document. For instance, nodes with  are not recognized

alltags := doc.Find("*") //doc is the HTML doc with the Google search

The selection does not contain the div tags with class="srg". The same applies to other class values such as "bkWMgd", "rc" for example.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before. I was trying to web scrape with python beautiful soup package and the same thing was happening.

Later it turned out that the html markup returned when trying to fetch it was actually the markup the server returned after finding a bot. I solved this by setting the `User-Agent` to `Mozilla/5.0`.

Hope this helps in your quest to solve this.
You can start by updating the code for the fetch request you have performed.

Comment: Also show what logs in your console when trying to console log the result from the fetch.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Actually, I already have a User-Agent set to Mozilla/5.0. How can I get some logs ? I can share the query with you and the list of tags that I get from the GoQuery selection

Comment: No i meant update your question with all the information.